# jQuery remove waypoint

Tags: jquery

I have an element that slides down when reaching the #news div, and slides up when passing the #news upon sliding up.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#news').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    if (direction === 'down') {
    $('#menu_list').animate({top: 10},{queue: false, duration:500}) ;}
    else {
    $('#menu_list').animate({top: 50},{queue: false, duration:500}) ;}
       }, {
    offset: '6'  
  });
});
```

I would like to know how to apply the " .waypoint('remove')   "  ? In order to make it slide up when leaving the div when sliding even futher down the site and going into other div. 
This way I could make animation like -  slide in / stop in position / slide out.

If waypoints isn't the correct plugin to do this I would really appreciate some indications how to achieve such effect.

Thanks !

Answer (score 8):

```
$('#news').waypoint('destroy') — Unregister waypoints and unbind all handlers.
$('#news').waypoint('remove') — Unregister waypoints but leave handlers intact.
```

Have you read the Waypoint full documentation ??

Src : http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#documentation

Comment: Yes, When I put $('#news').waypoint('remove') to the code, it gets removed instatly, and not after reaching the #news div, and when it's removed, the 'else' won't work.